# The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application : Getting KeyError KeyError: 'main' Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, api

KeyError

KeyError: 'main'
Traceback (most recent call last)

The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.

To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/temperature', methods=['POST'])
def temperature():
    zipcode = request.form['zip']
    r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip='+zipcode+',us&appid=fd38d62aa4fe1a03d86eee91fcd69f6e')
    json_object = r.json()
    temp_k = float(json_object['main']['temp'])
    temp_f = (temp_k - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32
    return render_template('temperature.html', temp=temp_f)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: is this all your code? Please may you provide the traceback. Tip: you should say what you've tried, and also provide all relevant data which includes tracebacks. That's why you're being down voted.

Comment: So instead of copying all the text that tells you how to get the traceback, why don't you post *the actual traceback*?

Comment: Make sure you have the correct keys in your `json_object` before trying to access them. also, it doesn't check for HTTP errors. what happen if they send a server error ?

Comment: Try print(zipcode) before the requests.get, to see if you're reading correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [API docs](http://openweathermap.org/current) it looks like your code should read the JSON correctly, so either your API key is not correct (the one you provided wasn't when I tried it, but you may have redacted it) or the Zip code you're requesting doesn't exist.

Either way, you should provide an error page:

```
@app.route('/temperature', methods=['POST'])
def temperature():
    zipcode = request.form['zip']
    r = requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip='+zipcode+',us&appid=fd38d62aa4fe1a03d86eee91fcd69f6e')
    json_object = r.json()
    try:
        temp_k = float(json_object['main']['temp'])
        temp_f = (temp_k - 273.15) * 1.8 + 32
        return render_template('temperature.html', temp=temp_f)
    except KeyError:
        msg = 'Unknown error'
        try:
            msg = json_object['message']
        except KeyError:
            pass

        print(msg)
        return render_template('temperature_error.html', error=msg)
```

It'll provide the error message given by the server, and so will indicate what the issue is.